# Xcode: Segue Show Transition Repeats Twice

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

I have 2 views, *Spring Element* and *Spring Insert Variables*. The user will click on the **Add** button, to change the view from *Spring Element* to *Spring Insert Variables* by Adaptive Segue - Show(eg.Push). User will then input the variables and **Submit**, to change the view from *Spring Insert Variables* back to *Spring Element* by Adaptive Segue - Show(eg.Push).

The problem is that the transition from *Spring Insert Variables* back to *Spring Element* repeats itself twice. [Video Illustration is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbpum4a3rma1djk/Segue%20Issue.mov?dl=0)

How do i correct it?

**Code for the Add Function**

```
@IBAction func Add(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addSpring", sender: sender)

}
```

**Code for submit function**

```
@IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("springSubmit", sender: sender)
}
```

[image: Storyboard View]

Comment: Looks like you have both action connected to `Submit` button and `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method call from `IBAction` callback. Isn't it?

Comment: add the code that you have written inside your add Button action method.i think problem is there in that method....

Comment: Remove that back segue. You should never segue backwards!

Comment: You cannot use a presentSegue for a dismissal. Use a unwind segue or just run `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated...` for  the click action

Comment: I try using `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated` to pass back datas, but doesn't work. Can anyone help out with this? [Question link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128386/swift-passing-datas-between-2-views-by-dismissviewcontrolleranimated)

Answer (score 0):

Remove segue from Spring Insert Variable to Spring Element.
    In submit action, add command:
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score -1):

you use push segue instead of push use custom segue
if you use push segue then remove -performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: method or use custom segue