# Xcode - Passing datas between 2 views by dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

I have used **dimissViewControllerAnimated** to return the view from *Spring Insert Variables* back to *Spring Element*. At the same time, my input datas should be passed from *Spring Insert Variables* back to *Sprint Element* by the function unwindSecondView in *Spring Element* class.

But apparently the datas are not pass, my arrays: force and stiffness still do not contain value. Can anyone advice on this?

**Code From Spring Insert Variables class**

```
class springInsertVariables : UIViewController {

var forceVar = [Float] ()
var stiffVar = [Float] ()
@IBOutlet weak var forceEntered: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var stiffnessEntered: UITextField!

@IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {

    forceVar.append((forceEntered.text as NSString).floatValue)
    stiffVar.append((stiffnessEntered.text as NSString).floatValue)

    println(forceVar) //This doesn't print on my output
    println(stiffVar) //This doesn't print on my output
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

   }
}
```

**Code From Spring Element Class**

```
 @IBAction func unwindSecondView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

     if let svcspringinsertvariables = segue.sourceViewController as? springInsertVariables {
        self.force = svcspringinsertvariables.forceVar
        self.stiffness = svcspringinsertvariables.stiffVar
        println(force)
        println(stiffness)
    }
}
```

[image: Storyboard of my 2 views]

Comment: You say forceVar and springVar do not print to your output from the Spring Insert class, so does that mean they are not set there?

Comment: It doesn't print on my debugger

Comment: Right, so if the values do not print, doesn't that mean they are empty and therefore when you pass them they are empty?

Comment: I am not too sure if is empty since it does't print. The println worked previously, when I tried creating a segue back to **Spring Element** by storyboard.

Comment: where do you instantiate your forceVar and stiffVar variables? Please update your question with that code.

Comment: @chrissukhram At the start of the class.

Comment: move the arrays outside of the class to be global variables

Comment: @chrissukhram I found where the problem is. I didn't link the submit button to the code itself. I'm trying to make this work now...

Comment: I linked it up and use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method suggested by @Rengers. It works now!

Comment: @chrissukhram I have a question. Previously, my println did not worked because I did not linked up the _Submit_ button to the code but why did the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dismissViewControllerAnimated` does not actually use the unwind segue. An unwind segue is like any other segue and must be performed using `performSegueWithIdentifier`.